# Azure DevOps: How to tell what was planned in a sprint?

Tags: azure-devops

Yes I can see what is currently in the sprint, but how can I tell what was originally planned in a sprint?
I would like to be able to query this for a chart on my dashboard. Additionally, I want to be able to pass this information over to Power Bi via  Analytics View.

Comment: You could try to check for the date of the change on the area path. Otherwise you might want to check out the REST API, you can pretty much pull out every single bit of data with it.

Comment: How would you check the date of the change on the area path?

Comment: @paulvalituttoHow did you set your original plan, by creating UserStory/PBI/Requirement?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to stories that are created and assigned to a sprint.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we create product backlog to correspond to your project plan, the roadmap for what your team plans to deliver. You create your product backlog by adding Issues (Basic process), User Stories (Agile), Product Backlog Items (Scrum), Requirements (CMMI).

Your backlog consists of a list of work items. You use work items to share information, assign work to team members, track dependencies, organize work, and more.

If you want to track your project plan, you should query your product backlog.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-quick-report?view=azure-devops

Comment: if you have a look at the velocity chart widget on the dashboard, you can have a better idea of what I am looking for. Once you have that up, you can see one of the column stacks is identified as "Planned". How can I expose that to power bi?

Comment: Planned - calculated based on the amount of work assigned to the sprint prior to the start of the sprint. You may check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi

Comment: The answer to the question then would be, how to query for the date work items are assigned to the sprint. How is that done?

Comment: You need to use api to get that information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/reporting%20work%20item%20revisions/read%20reporting%20revisions%20get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1